# How to create a parabolic motion?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

How can I create a parabolic motion like the one in the picture.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `parabola` path which you can use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.7pt]
\draw [->] (-.2,0)node[below]{$o$}--(4.5,0)node[below]{$x$};
\draw [->] (0,-.2)--(0,2)node[left]{$y$};
\draw (0,0) parabola[parabola height=1.2cm] (4,0);
\draw [->] (0,0)--(55:2);
\draw (0:.7cm)node[above left]{$\alpha$} arc (0:55:.7cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To begin using pgfplots :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,]
    \addplot[domain=0:5,
    ] {-(.5*x)*(x-5)};
    \draw[->,] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,3);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]